# Using include tag inside strings.xml

Tags: android, xml

So, if I have a strings1.xml, and a strings2.xml, can I have a strings.xml like this one?:

```
<resources>
    <include src="@xml/strings1"/>

    <include src="@xml/strings2"/>
</resources>
```

I have tried it, and its not working, when In try to compile says

```
Can't determine type for tag <include src="@xml/strings1"/>
```

but maybe is because I am doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to merge xml's inside of strings.xml. All xmls inside of values folder are already merged on build step.

Just create strings1.xml and strings2.xml and delete strings.xml in values folder.

Names of the xml files inside of res/values folder are not important.

You can manually merge all value xmls like that:

`my_app_values.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="purple_200">#FFBB86FC</color>
    <color name="purple_500">#FF6200EE</color>
    <color name="purple_700">#FF3700B3</color>
    <color name="teal_200">#FF03DAC5</color>
    <color name="teal_700">#FF018786</color>
    <color name="black">#FF000000</color>
    <color name="white">#FFFFFFFF</color>
    <string name="app_name">My Application</string>
    <style name="Theme.MyApplication" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light.NoActionBar" />
</resources>
```

Comment: I knokw that. What I am asking is if I can use include tag in a strings.xml file. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: I cannot find any documentation mentions include tag or anything similiar inside resources xml. Auto completion on Android Studio also does not list anything like that.

Only place i see the include tag is inside the layout xmls.